# JavaScript backgroundImage broken by $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, image, background, document-ready

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function backgroundImage() {
document.body.style.backgroundImage='url("http://www.image.jpg")';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="backgroundImage()">
Content here
</body> 
</html>
```

But the addition of document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.body.style.backgroundImage='url("http://www.image.jpg")';
});
```

breaks the code

Why does this not work, something I'm missing, or prefix of document.ready just not needed? Could it be that 'document' should not be called twice?

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,
Dale

Comment: Do you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: @alex most probably that is the case

Comment: Probably it is what @alex says, no jquery included.

Comment: I think you're right, I made a test page without external CSS/JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem, can run

http://jsfiddle.net/HRhQW/

Comment: Thanks, tested on my own demo page and it works. No need for the 'body onload' anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the name of the function from 'backgroundImage' to something like 'setBackgrounImage'. The name is somehow conflicting with the property.

**Update**: I guess I was wrong, See this jsfiddle.net/ARsmn. The body onload function is called after the $(document).ready(). So you might want to keep this in your mind when using body body onload and $(document).ready().

Comment: I guess I was wrong, See this http://jsfiddle.net/ARsmn/. The body onload function is called after the $(document).ready().

Comment: in the case where it breaks, he is not using function name.